# Getting error on running command npm start

Tags: npm

I am trying to run the project its given following error.

> npm start error Failed at the nedben-fe@0.0.1 start script ' grunt
>   live'.

I tried the following but it did not work

```
npm i findup-sync  --save
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install` first?

Comment: Ya,  I rum npm install then npm strat after that its give error